# Perl DBD :: JDBC module issue No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb

Tags: perl, jdbc

I am using Strawberry Perl 5.28 version and end up getting issues while installing DBD::JDBC module .
Hence the make/gmake , make test,gmake test is consistently failing even if I download the DBC::JDBC module and run perl Makefile.PL . I already have JDK 8 and JRE installed.
Any help would be appreciated .

```
C:\Users>cpan DBD::JDBC DBI
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.217)
Database was generated on Thu, 20 May 2021 14:53:47 GMT
Running install for module 'DBD::JDBC'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.086)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\V\VI\VIZDOM\DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.32)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.77)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
Configuring V/VI/VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Using DBI 1.643 (for perl 5.028002 on MSWin32-x64-multi-thread) installed in C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DBD::JDBC
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for V/VI/VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20190420)
cp JDBC.pod blib\lib\DBD\JDBC.pod
cp lib/Bundle/DBD/JDBC.pm blib\lib\Bundle\DBD\JDBC.pm
cp JDBC.pm blib\lib\DBD\JDBC.pm
  VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe -- OK
Running make test for VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz
set CLASSPATH=dbd_jdbc.jar;t/hsqldb/hsqldb-1.8.0.2.jar;t/hsqldb/log4j-1.2.13.jar;C:\Users\Downloads\DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar\DBD-JDBC-0.71\log4j.properties;C:\Users\Downloads\SimbaSparkJDBC4-2.6.16.1020\SparkJDBC4.jar;
"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01_env.t ...... ok
t/02_connect.t .. 1/5 DBD::JDBC::dr connect warning: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:t/hsqldb/testdb at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/DBI.pm line 679.

#   Failed test 'connected'
#   at t/02_connect.t line 40.
t/02_connect.t .. 3/5 # Connection error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:t/hsqldb/testdb
# Make sure your CLASSPATH includes your JDBC driver.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 5.
t/02_connect.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/5 subtests
        (less 2 skipped subtests: 2 okay)
t/03_hsqldb.t ... 1/22 DBD::JDBC::dr connect warning: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:t/hsqldb/testdb at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/DBI.pm line 679.

#   Failed test 'connected'
#   at t/03_hsqldb.t line 34.
t/03_hsqldb.t ... 2/22 # Connection error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:t/hsqldb/testdb
# Looks like your test exited with 1 just after 22.
t/03_hsqldb.t ... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/22 subtests
        (less 20 skipped subtests: 1 okay)
t/basis.t ....... skipped: BASIS URL not defined
t/oracle.t ...... skipped: Oracle URL not defined

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02_connect.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 5 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/03_hsqldb.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 22 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=5, Tests=32,  7 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr +  0.02 sys =  0.06 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/5 test programs. 2/32 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:780: test_dynamic] Error 255
  VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'DBD::JDBC'.
DBI is up to date (1.643).
```

Comment: Have a look at the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/VIZDOM/DBD-JDBC-0.71/README) file, it says *"The Java classes and their source code are provided in     dbd_jdbc.jar. Copy this file to a location of your choice. See the DBD::JDBC documentation (JDBC.pod) for instructions on running the server."*

Comment: C:\Strawberry\cpan\build\DBD-JDBC-0.71-0  location already had dbd_jdbc.jar , JDBC.pod , JDBC.pm file ... and thats what the cpan tries to install ... still have same issue

Answer (score 1):

After lot of fight I have found easy way to resolve this problem to install DBD::JDBC is to download this module as tar file : DBD-JDBC-0.71.tar from CPAN and navigate to path where Strawberry Perl is installed like C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\DBD and move all files from extracted tar to here . then JDBC should start working .